# Why does xdotool type twice ? How can I avoid it?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, xdotool

`[Wed Aug 05 20:49:43 deppfx@localhost:~] $xdotool type password` 

`password[Wed Aug 05 20:50:51 deppfx@localhost:~] $password`

How can I avoid this ? Can someone please explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 3):

@Wnoise is right!

But if you insist you can do this:

```
stty -echo && xdotool type password && stty echo
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57083493/6178853), one could add `tput el1` before `echo` such that

```
xdotool type password; tput el1; echo
```

This will erase the unnecessary contents, creating a blank line after the previous prompt (which is also unnecessary)

```
[Wed Aug 05 20:49:43 deppfx@localhost:~]$ xdotool type password; tput el1; echo

[Wed Aug 05 20:49:43 deppfx@localhost:~]$ password
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually typing twice; it's typing while it has control of the terminal, then the shell prompt returns and reformats what got typed at the terminal.  Try typing into a different xterm (e.g. `xdotool selectwindow type password`), and you should see only one copy.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. How can I avoid this ? I am trying to automate pasting clipboard using xdotool and so I can't use the `selectwindow` option.

Comment: @deppfx: There is nothing to avoid.  It really is just typing it once.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread "xdotool type duplicates"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/xdotool-users/RwtDN8s_vFI/Ff6adt7SpQsJ) explains the reason:

> That's not twice. Explaining why this appears requires a bit of detail
>   on how shells and terminals behave.
>
> You can observe this yourself with normal keyboard typing by running
>   this:
>
> % sleep 5
>
> And while sleep is running, type "hello world" in the same terminal.
>   When sleep exits and returns you to your shell prompt, you will see
>   something like this:
>
> nightfall(~) % sleep 5
>
> hello worldnightfall(~) % hello world
>
> What is happening is you typing into the terminal while sleep runs (or
>   xdotool), sleep doesn't read from stdin, so when the shell is given
>   control again it reads your keystrokes (in the input buffer) and
>   prints them on the screen showing you what you see above.

My current workaround is add an extra `echo`, e.g.:

```
xdotool type password; echo
```

which output:

```
[Wed Aug 05 20:49:43 deppfx@localhost:~]$ xdotool type password; echo
password
[Wed Aug 05 20:49:43 deppfx@localhost:~]$ password
```

This doesn't erase the previous line but at least prevent your prompt growth too long occupied by duplicated commands.